# Is there any way to avoid google chart repeaters

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I'm using JSON to draw multiple charts using google charts library.
so i call the function dynamically. this is my code : 
How i can my functions

```
$.getJSON(destination, params = null, function(data){
  $.each(data, function(chartName, chartData){
    window[chartName](chartData);
  });
});
```

example of my functions that in a dynamic way

```
function drawme(){
// prepare the chart data
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Browser');
data.addColumn('number','range');
data.addRows([
        ["Javascript",10],
        ["Images",30],
        ["HTML",20],
        ["CSS",30],
        ["Other",10]
]);
var options = {"pieHole":0.4, "width":100, "height":100,'legend':'none', 'chartArea': {'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'}};
// draw the chart
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("pageSpeed"));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

My PHP Code :

```
<?php
  echo json_encode(array('drawme'=> array()));
 ?>
```

every thing is ok with me, my problem is how can i avoid the repeaters of 
this line : `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawme);`
is there any way to it dynamically also

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` only needs to be called once per page load,
then you can draw as many charts as needed.

you can also use the promise the `load` statement returns instead.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawme);
```

in addition, the `load` statement will wait for the page to load by default.
as such, you can use `google.charts.load` in place of `$(document).ready`

I would recommend loading google first, get that out of the way,
then load the json and draw all the chart you need...

something like the following setup...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $.getJSON(destination, params = null, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(chartName, chartData){
      drawChart(chartName, chartData);
    });
  });
});
```